# How to add a image url to feed as a item child?

Tags: image, wordpress, feed

Is there a way to add the thumbnail image url to the wordpress feed??

I know how to add the thumbnail image to the_content, but i need the rss feed to layout a page  on another domain. So i was just thinking of using $item->get_title(), $item->get_description() and for the thumbnail something like $item->get_image_url

On the other domain.com i use the following (other domain.com is also a WP install)

```
require( '../../../site/wp-load.php' );
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rss= fetch_feed('domain.com/feed/?post_type=recipes');
foreach($rss->get_items() as $item) {

    echo $item->get_title().'<br/>'.$item->get_description();
    echo '<hr/>';

}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image url (src)

you have to use first [get_post_thumbnail_id](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)  to get the thumb id then use  [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) to get the image src

```
<?php
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id , $size, $icon ); 
?>
```

Comment: tx but yes i tried. That's the function mostly used to add an image to the rss-feed $item->descreption. In my case i guess, i like to add a node to the simpliepie <item> for example <image>.  If i understand correctly WP uses some sort of simplepie format for the rss feed, but i doesn't include the image so it seems. I tried get_image_url ();

Comment: ah ok i see where you are going and i have the original img src with `$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'full' ); ` but still i don't see how i can put this url into the rss feed with `add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_post_thumbnail');function rss_post_thumbnail($content) {global $post;if( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) )
  $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
  $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, 'full'); //where to put $image_src[0] in the rss feed?
  $content = '<p>'.$image_src[0].'</p>'.$content;return $content;
 
}`

Comment: could you edit your question above with your last update because the code in the comment is not readable :)

Comment: Hi Bouchaala, hmm can't edit anymore. What i liked to accomplish is to add the value of `$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, 'full');` as a seperate node in the rss feed and not as part of the content node.

Comment: FYI: i am now playing with editing wp-includes/feed-rss2.php altough i would like to add it to functions.php and leave feed-rss2.php untouch.

Comment: So i have add this to feed-rss2 

`<?php if ( 'recipe' == get_post_type() ){?>
<test><?php echo rss_post_image();?></test>
<?php }?>` 

and rss_post_image() is just a function which returns the image url. Now i can parse the item -> test node as a seperate image url. 
Is there a way i can use a hook/filter so the code is added to feed-rss2.php from functions.php???

Comment: what i know is that you are not able to add an img node on the article node, this is not specified on RSS.